# why my view state not getting cleared and on reload it save the value to the databse again?

Tags: asp.net

I am having user control registered on a aspx page.

there is a button on user control resisted on some aspx page that perform some action to store the value of viewste to the database, and below that i have cleared my viewstate value, but if i do right click and reload the page it reinsert the values to the data base, what i am missing or the viewstate do not get cleared, how should i prevent it to resave the same entries to the database.

I am partially writing my code below.

```
 protected void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["dtQuestions"] != null)
        {
          foreach (DataRow dr in dtQuestions.Rows)
            {
                int currQueScore = GetAnswerScore(dr["AnswerType"].ToString().Trim(), dr["ClientAnswerValue"].ToString().Trim());
                dr["ClientAnswerScore"] = currQueScore;
                myScore += currQueScore;
                SurveyClientAnswer objDetail = new SurveyClientAnswer();
                objDetail.SurveyClientID = objMaster.SurveyClientID;
                objDetail.QuestionID = int.Parse(dr["QuestionID"].ToString());
                objDetail.Answer = dr["ClientAnswerValue"].ToString();
                objDetail.Score = int.Parse(dr["ClientAnswerScore"].ToString());
                DB.SurveyClientAnswers.InsertOnSubmit(objDetail);
                DB.SubmitChanges();
            }
            objMaster.FinalScore = myScore;
            DB.SubmitChanges();

            ViewState["dtQuestions"] = null;
        }
 else 
        {
            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            pnl.Visible = true;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you prompted to re-submit POST information on refresh?

Comment: You can ether redirect to avoid refresh, or detect the refresh.

Comment: Could some body please help me with this, how should i manger it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinsert the data, simply create a unique constraint on the database to disallow this scenario.

As far as doing it in code, you could possibly only insert the data adding this condition to the `if` statement:

```
if(IsPostBack && (ViewState["dtQuestions"] != null)
{
    //meaning the user is not simply reloading the page but actually posting back
}
```

Note that there might be some corner cases where this won't work. Without testing is difficult to know but I strongly believe that this should be handled at the database level instead.

Comment: So what actualy reload meaning? does it go to through whole life cycle of page? also my major concern is that when i have cleared viwestate how does it resend values to DB?

Comment: *does it go to through whole life cycle of page?* -> Every page load or postback goes through the page life cycle. You only clear the ViewState when the button is clicked, a simple page reload will still have the same values you had initially put in ViewState

Comment: But i see after attaching break points, if i reload it still hit the submit button and clear the viewstate..i am pretty confuse on it logically, could you please elaborate a little from page life cycle point of view?